# Why was my question (1801790) closed?

Tags: discussion

[How to upgrade the software called Everything published by Void Tools?](https://superuser.com/questions/1801790/how-to-upgrade-the-software-called-everything-published-by-void-tools)

The reason that was given is "details or clarity," which clearly isn't the issue.

---

There are a couple of answers and comments that overlap, so I'll answer here.

"Clean installation" was a poor choice of words since it also has a technical meaning. The rest of the paragraph explains what I meant: no unnecessary traces are left.

My question was simple. So simple that adding info just complicated it. Adding reasoning for people who thought it was trivial turned the whole thing to something philosophical.

Anyway, I cleaned the question and posted a full detailed answer.

Comment: 5 people said that was the issue. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: When it was closed your question contained zero details of what your problem actually was with updating it or what you had tried. At that time it was definitely unclear. You currently have two votes to reopen so apparently some people think you have improved it with your edit.

Comment: I'm referring to my original post, title and body. I simply asked if I need to uninstall the old version before installing the new one. I didn't think that much elaboration on the motivation is needed (installing a service twice, locked files, clattering the installed app list, etc.), but I added one example, "Would my config be preserved?" In your opinion, was the question unclear and missing details, or was it an ego issue of a reputable user who missed that I'm referring to a specific app (missing the tag and capital E)?

Comment: @Zohar - Your question was originally not clear, I was one of those close votes, an edit happened to your question which clarified your question. However, while I thought I retracted my close vote, I did not retract it. However, the question can be reopened, all you have to do is wait until that happens. You won't be install the service twice, you will remove the existing service, then reinstall it.  You made no mention of Everything being installed as a service in your question.  So I made no mention of it in my answer. Your question needed work, and it's been improved, continue to improve it

Comment: IMO that question in it's current state is a train wreck. It's a Q&A to comment section.

Comment: First of all, going for "ego" notes when you're in need in help is not the best move ever. Especially when the user was perfectly right that the title was confusing. If the app name is the same as an English word that could have a different meaning when not capitalized, it's intuitive that you should pay attention to the letter casing. Secondly, any of your versions of the question lacked focus, IMO. "How to upgrade an app?" together with different questions in the body is way too broad, questions on the websites should be specific to help others.

Comment: And the proof is in answers, which don't answer the "How to upgrade?" question from the title, but part of the more detailed questions in body instead - "Do I need to uninstall?" and "Are configs preserved?".

Answer (score 9):

Even now, after 8 revisions, it is still a tangled mess of meta-responses to things in comments.

The title is 'how to upgrade', halfway down the body you mention 'clean install' which is definitely not a standard update/upgrade.

A question in its final form needs to be able to stand alone, even if the comments are removed. Comments are to enable clarification of a question, & should not form part of the final structure.

Answer (score 7):

I do not believe I voted to close your question yesterday, but I did see it (and commented on it).

Ramhound found that the software documentation, available online from the publisher, gave instructions answering the question as you asked it.

Your question did not mention multiple instances, and the "however" link you shared in response to the found documentation indicates that multiple instances have a clear delineation, via "named instances", which your question also did not mention. Not until some further edit did you note you were trying to do a clean install, but taken together with the rest of your comments, it is still not clear if you want a "clean" install or to maintain your config, because a "clean" install strongly implies you want to remove/reset any existing config.

As it stands, the answer given that points to the Voidtools documentation *still* answers the question that you've asked, and therefore still indicates you have not done the "homework" we hope is done beforehand.

AN ASIDE: *This site is run by volunteers, not employees. We expect that someone puts forth some effort in research and self-attempts prior to asking questions here, because what is being done when asking is that you are asking the community to put forth effort on your behalf. When someone has already tried things, and demonstrates and documents that effort, their questions are more likely to be well received, not least of which because the community knows what not to suggest, and won't have to resort to simply suggesting "read the manual".*

Your current question has more information, but this additional information has made things less clear, and still doesn't give any sort of strong evidence your question has not already been clearly answered by the documentation from the publisher. It seems to me that your should take a good backup and simply follow the steps in the documentation. If that works, great, you've answered your question. If that doesn't work, now you have more, better, clearer information we can work with to get you a good answer to a better question.

Comment: While I agree with this answer, it's important to take note, I have withdrawn my answer since the question despite being reopened is actively NOT being improved.